# How to Parse the txt file in c#

Tags: c#, parsing, visual-studio-2012

Hello I am new to C# and I have to parse the text file formatted which has the data like following.

```
H1|57535                 |65644474|       243.34
D1|671690160540      |FedEx Gnd   |Ground          |Parcel |06082016
D2|FCREADHCU3     |    10||||||     23.01
H1|57521                 |65642336|       923.31
D1|671690161010      |FedEx Gnd   |Ground          |Parcel |06082016
D2|PS121B         |     1|      0.00
H1|57521                 |65642336|       923.31
D1|671690161031      |FedEx Gnd   |Ground          |Parcel |06082016
D2|PS121B         |     1|      0.00
H1|57521                 |65642336|       923.31
D1|671690161020      |FedEx Gnd   |Ground          |Parcel |06082016
D2|PS121B         |     1|      0.00
snipping
```

How can I parse text file  in C#. Help Is appreciated.

Comment: Do a google search

Comment: Briefly looking at your data, there are 3 different lines of fixed length fields, look at the first 2 characters to determine which format to use. You will have to count the characters to determine each field length.

Comment: Please don't post an image of your text if you expect an answer - we need the raw text if we are to help. You should post your text in `<pre></pre>` tags in your question.

Comment: @Enigmativity, Sure will keep that in mind.

Comment: @UrvilShah 20 minutes later.. there is still only a screenshot. You can [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/37737777/edit)

Comment: @UrvilShah - Please don't just keep it in mind. Please edit your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with this:

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines("<your path/filename>");
var stringBags = lines.Select(l => l.Split('|'));
var objects = stringBags.Select(b => new {Id = b[0], Name = b[1], SomeOtherField = b[2]});
```

This gives you a way to parse the file, and to project it into some sort of object you can deal with

Comment: If you're going to process line-by-line, then use `File.ReadLines`. Only use `ReadAllLines` if you *must* have all of the lines in memory at the same time.

Comment: How can I split the data based on H1, D1 and D2, because those are field headers and I want field headers data associiated with it. So like , Data for each H1 , data for each D1, data for each D2 .

Answer (score 0):

You could do a foreach loop for each line in the file and parse the string...

```
foreach (string line in File.ReadAllLines("filepath"))
```

Comment: If you're going to process line-by-line, then use `File.ReadLines`. Only use `ReadAllLines` if you *must* have all of the lines in memory at the same time.