# How to parse on the repeating header field.

Tags: c#, parsing

I already posted question on stack overflow. I used delimiter to parse the data. 
but in my text file I have repetitive header fields on which I have to again split the data. I am new to c# and I tried searching on google too , but didn't found the close solution too. Help In appreciated. Again the data is.

```
H1|57535                 |65644474|       243.34
D1|671690160540      |FedEx Gnd   |Ground          |Parcel |06082016
D2|FCREADHCU3     |    10||||||     23.01
H1|57521                 |65642336|       923.31
D1|671690161010      |FedEx Gnd   |Ground          |Parcel |06082016
D2|PS121B         |     1|      0.00
H1|57521                 |65642336|       923.31
D1|671690161031      |FedEx Gnd   |Ground          |Parcel |06082016
D2|PS121B         |     1|      0.00
H1|57521                 |65642336|       923.31
D1|671690161020      |FedEx Gnd   |Ground          |Parcel |06082016
D2|PS121B         |     1|      0.00
```

I wanted value of H1, D1 , D2 and then for each H1 value I am going to store value in database.

Link to same question asked : [How to Parse the txt file in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37737777/how-to-parse-the-txt-file-in-c-sharp/37737925#37737925)

Comment: Show us what you've tried so we can help you. You have two questions now and zero code to show for it. There are sites where you can pay money, such as $15, to have someone write the code for you if you need. This is not a '"write my code for me" site.

Comment: @Quantic I am not asking to write code for me. I am asking the approach to deal with. So should I design my regex to deal with parsing the file or is there any better "approach". Thanks for your input though.

Comment: We still need to see code. Every 3 lines is one shipment, so parse 3 lines, then take the data you gathered from each and send them to database. Then do the next 3 lines, etc.. Needs validation to ensure each line is what you think it is and that the 3 lines really are a part of the same shipment, etc..

Comment: Parse each line. If it starts with "H" then it's a header record. If it starts with "D", it's a detail record. No need to bother with regex here. Just read the line, String.Split('|') and look at the array you get back.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try code like this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input =
            "H1|57535                 |65644474|       243.34\n" +
            "D1|671690160540      |FedEx Gnd   |Ground          |Parcel |06082016\n" +
            "D2|FCREADHCU3     |    10|     23.01\n" +
            "H1|57521                 |65642336|       923.31\n" +
            "D1|671690161010      |FedEx Gnd   |Ground          |Parcel |06082016\n" +
            "D2|PS121B         |     1|      0.00\n" +
            "H1|57521                 |65642336|       923.31\n" +
            "D1|671690161031      |FedEx Gnd   |Ground          |Parcel |06082016\n" +
            "D2|PS121B         |     1|      0.00\n" +
            "H1|57521                 |65642336|       923.31\n" +
            "D1|671690161020      |FedEx Gnd   |Ground          |Parcel |06082016\n" +
            "D2|PS121B         |     1|      0.00\n";

            StringReader reader = new StringReader(input);
            string inputLine = "";
            Package package = null;
            while ((inputLine = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                inputLine = inputLine.Trim();
                if(input.Length > 0)
                {
                    string[] splitRow = inputLine.Split(new char[] {'|'}).Select(x => x.Trim()).ToArray();

                    switch(splitRow[0])
                    {
                        case "H1" :
                            package = new Package();
                            package.id1 = splitRow[1];
                            package.id2 = splitRow[2];
                            package.weight = Decimal.Parse(splitRow[3]);
                            break;
                        case "D1" :
                            package.id3 = splitRow[1];
                            package.type1 = splitRow[2];
                            package.type2 = splitRow[3];
                            package.type3 = splitRow[4];
                            package.id4 = splitRow[5];
                            break;
                        case "D2" :
                            package.id5 = splitRow[1];
                            package.quantity = int.Parse(splitRow[2]);
                            package.cost = decimal.Parse(splitRow[3]);
                            StorePackage(package);
                            package = null;
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        static void StorePackage(Package package)
        {
        }
    }
    public class Package
    {
        public int quantity { get; set; }
        public string id1 { get; set; }
        public string id2 { get; set; }
        public string id3 { get; set; }
        public string id4 { get; set; }
        public string id5 { get; set; }
        public string type1 { get; set; }
        public string type2 { get; set; }
        public string type3 { get; set; }
        public decimal weight { get; set; }
        public decimal cost { get; set; }


    }
}
```

Comment: It Works perfectly . Thanks @Jdweng